# repositioning UITabBar in a UITabBarController on iPad does not work

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have this code which works on iPhone:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = [tabBar frame];
    frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 20, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [tabBar setFrame: frame];
}
```

This one places the UITabBarController's tabBar on top just below the status bar.

But the same code does not work on the iPad. The tabBar would still stick at the bottom.

Would you guys have any idea?

Comment: did you try printing the frame values before & after the repositioning ?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?  I'm having the same issue.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the frame resetting itself when the iPad is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 20, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

Check where set origin y=20 ,you are entering static 20 value.